# Jquery toggle class on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so i'm tring to make a header navbar that grow when hovered on, and autohides when the cursor leaves the area.

I want it, when hovered on, to grow in height. I am doing this by trying to toggle a class `isShown`

to do this I was going to use a modifier class that increases the height from 0.2em to 2em.
additionally because the bar is so small when hidden I have another element invisible div wrapping the element that is double its height in order to pick up a hovering cursor in the headers proximity.

these are the css classes:

```
.hover_box{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;

  top:0;

  height:4em;
  width:100%;
}

header{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;

  top:0;
  height:0.2em;
  width:100%;

  background-color:#FFBB00;
}

header.isShown{
  height:2em;
}
```

I see nothing wrong with the classes, but what's wrong I believe is in the Jquery that I wrote handle the "mouseover" event.

Here is the code that I used for the event handling:

```
$("header, .hover_box").mouseover(function(e){
    console.log("hovered over header")
    let elem = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
    console.log("${e.target.tagName} targeted")
    elem.toggleClass("isShown");
  } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `elem.toggleClass("isShown")` but defined `elem` from a `getElementsByTagName()` call. [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is a jQuery method. [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) is a native method, and doesn't return a jQuery object, but gets the native DOM elements. So `elem` isn't a jQuery object. This should have given you an error on the javascript console about `toggleClass()` not being a function.

To fix this either make `elem` a jQuery object

```
let elem = jQuery("header");
elem.toggleClass("isShown")
```

Or use the native [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) call

```
elem.classList.toggle("isShown");
```

Comment: yeah I see my mistake now, but i just ried that and for some reason it isn't helping me, i might have something else going on. if would be so inclided do you mind checking the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Leviathan_The_Great/pen/eywGqz?editors=1111) that I have this code running in?

Comment: just from checking the console, I can't seem to get the event to fire

Comment: @Leviathan_the_Great your codepen doesn't work because you have a syntax error in your code, and you also didn't include the jQuery library

Comment: that explains it!, I didn't see any syntax error because of babel, but i did completly miss that i had taken Jquery out of the project. thanks so much!

Comment: hmmm, i managed to fix the Jquery issue but babel doesn't seem to be giving me any errors at all. though my code still isn't running. This one has got me stooped. though I can probably diagnose this myself at this point. Thanks!